# Different instances on deserialization of php objects?

Tags: php

Suppose I have a class called MyClass, with a member variable 'var'.
And the following scenario:

```
echo '<pre>';
$x=new MyClass;
$y=new MyClass;
$x->var=$y;
echo 'Checking for $x->var===$y :'.($x->var===$y).PHP_EOL; // outputs 1

$xs=serialize($x);
$ys=serialize($y);

$xsu=unserialize($xs);
$ysu=unserialize($ys);
echo 'Checking for $xsu->var===$ysu :'.($xsu->var===$ysu); //outputs nothing
```

After serializing and de-serializing, the instances are different.
The php runtime creates a different object and unserializes it. Should it not look at some object hash and return reference to the same object(after  de-serializing once).
My qs. is what could be the drawbacks?

Edit:
I need identical references because of the following reason stated in 2 points: (Please correct if I am wrong)
Objects can be serialized to disk in individual 1 file per object design. 1. Their file name could be returned as a reference string from the serialize() method. While deserializing, the file can be read from the disk and the object manipulated.
2.So, now if I get identical references, any changes made to one would get reflected in the other, which could not be the case if the references are different. At the end, the single entity could be saved to the disk.

Comment: The `unserialize()` method is not static, and I think it cannot be, because it sets the internal state of the current object on which it is called.

Comment: But as per above, the  $xsu=unserialize($xs) and $ysu=unserialize($ys); Here, $xsu->var === $ysu returns false as 2 different objects are created. But before serializing, they were 1.

Comment: No, it should not do that.  It'd be counter intuitive in most languages. Objects are typically handled by reference.  If you need to compare by value, you might be able to compare hashes of the serialized objects.

Comment: @GrandmasterB . Say my above scenario, after de serializing, the references $xsu->var and $ysu are different now. Any changes made into properties of one won't affect other, which would not have been the case prior to serialization. I was thinking of having some virtual name or address of every php object which could be used while serializing instead of hash, which could guarantee a unique name and single object creation.

Comment: @Praveen, it looks to me like you're running into the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Given your example it seems like you're missing the point of serialization, so what is it that you hope to achieve at a high level?

Comment: @zzzzBov . Do you have a solution to offer? I want same objects after deserialization as before.

Comment: @praveen, except you'll never get duplicate references from deserializaion. You've missed the point of my previous comment. You need to explain *why you think you need identical references*. You don't need identical references, you need a better solution. Reread the xy problem link I posted previously.

Comment: @zzzzBov .  I am extremely sorry then sir/mam for my last comment. Thanks for correcting. I have edited the question and provided details  below the text 'Edit'. Please see to it and correct me further, or any solution if you could suggest.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the asker lacks a fundamental understanding of how serialization works and is asking how to do something that isn't possible.

Comment: @zzzzBov . I do know how serialization works. I also know that for the current Php implementation, this is impossible. So, I was asking a workaround for this!

Answer (score 1):

- To achieve something like that the runtime will need to keep track of all objects in some table and have to lookup & update this table
  every time it creates an object. This cost is high and the benefit is
  not very clear.
- As internal states of every object keep changing, the behaviour won't be easy to understand when you want to deserialise data of one object that has been serialised in different spacetime.
- You can achieve this specific behaviour by overriding __sleep() and __wakeup() and not changing php runtime.
- Compatibility.

Comment: Yes, that would be costly(maybe much). Well, I am working for some solution to this where the object would be saved to the disk and retrieved whenever required( as can already be done by implementing serializable). But, this would be unique as wheresoever the object would be referenced from, the reference would only be given. In case of deserializing, the object would be brought from the disk once, and the reference would be updated. So, there would be no nested objects in serialized string. The limitations could be private and maybe, protected variables too, as can't be accessed from outside.